# Android Chrome: Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-native://newtab/

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

From an Android Activity I try to open chrome by Intent passing a URL.
It usually works!!!!
Chrome is launched and page displayed.

Problem is that  "sometimes",  maybe after many times i run tests,
the URL is not loaded, chrome doesn't even try, a blank page is displayed;
debugging with chrome for desktop: inspect devices  the only log is in the console and it says:

> Blockquote

"Not allowed to load local resource: chrome-native://newtab/"

I launch chrome like this:

```
try {
       Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
       i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"));
       i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
       i.setData(Uri.parse(url));          
       i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_CREATE_NEW_TAB,true);
    //   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(i);
   }
   catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
       // Chrome is not installed
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
       i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_CREATE_NEW_TAB,true);
       startActivity(i);
   }
```

1. Killing and restarting chrome is not Helping; Restarting the phone is!
2. No Local resources is loaded;  URL is just www.blablabla.com
3. The  URL Page access the phone camera by webRTC, but the error is before the page loads.
4. The app that launches chrome has background process for realtime comunication with websockets

i have already met errors of the kind: Not allowed to load local resource etc..
but only when i try to access local resources like files etc...

the very error:
Not allowed to load local resource:  chrome-native://newtab/
gives no result on the web.

any help???

Comment: Try the code: `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL( "chrome-native://newtab/", html, "text/html", 
"utf-8", null );` See reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Tag [tag:google-chrome-app] is **not** for the mobile browser.

Comment: I am not trying to load the page in a WebView, and I don't want to.
The latest HTML5, Javascript and WebRTC features are only available on the earlier releases of Chrome, Firefox or Opera.
That's why i set the package name "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"  in the intent.

Comment: Hey, @gaugeinvariante , did you figure it out?